why doesn’t MyMethod return a value even though it uses Console.WriteLine()
I was studying C# on w3schools when i saw this code.
My question is: MyMethod shouldn't return a value, since there is a "Console.WriteLine()" and a default parameter at the method?
And why Main method return those 3 calls normally,
(There's nothing wrong with the code, i just want to understand why)
static void MyMethod(string country = "Norway")
{
  Console.WriteLine(country);
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
  MyMethod("Sweden");
  MyMethod("India");
  MyMethod();
  MyMethod("USA");
}

Output:
// Sweden
// India
// Norway
// USA

What i expected:
// Norway (from the first method)
// Sweden
// India
// Norway
// USA


Minor nit: none of these methods "returns" anything; they might provide output (to the console), but that's different

Why did you expect your program to print out 5 lines when the method that prints something is only called 4 times? If you don't call a method, nothing else will - it would be a world wide disaster if C# decided to randomly invoke methods in programs for no reason/without being explicitly told to do it

@flackoverstow Just imagine this is the very first C# code you are looking at and your impression (or misconception) is that all of it should be executed from top down. I blame top-level statements for that :D

@flackoverstow my inference here is that it wasn't made clear to Pietro that the Main method is special, and is started because it is the entry point. If we don't think of Main as special, then we should expect either nothing at all to happen, or 5 lines of output

@Fildor my counter to that would be that if we were starting from scratch, top-level statements make a lot more sense than a magic Main method. But I agree that having both may be confusing. Time to deprecate Main, then :)

@MarcGravell Granted and agreed. I think what is so confusing about them is that we can have either. And frankly, I think that should be the first lesson: "Entrypoint is Main, but there is also "toplevel" ....". Does it make sense?

"Time to deprecate Main, then :)" - Haha, hot take. I'm still on the fence on that.

@fildor yes, but I don't always presume to guess at what misapprehensions a learner is laboring under, hence my serious question as to why they think 5 lines should output. Once I know how their perception differs from reality it makes it easier to correct

@flackoverstow Valid point. Sometimes I read more into a text than I should.


MyMethod shouldn't return a value, since there is a "Console.WriteLine()" and a default parameter at the method?

No. It's because its return type is void.
Your expectation deviates from your observation because of a misconception.
The Main method is the "Entry Point" to your Program. It will be called when you execute your program (or hit "Run" in the IDE).
The MyMethod is a method that is not "automatically" called. It will only be executed if something (i.e. your code) calls it. And finally everything that can call it will somehow be traceable back to the Main method. Admittedly, that's a little bit under-complex, but to understand why you observe what you observe, it should be enough.
So, when your program is started it will jump to Main, then execute those 4 calls to MyMethod and exit.

EDIT: As Marc lays down in his answer (rightfully), there are top-level statements now. But for one, I think for beginners, that must be pretty confusing, so for starters, I'd go with the "traditional" Main. Their existence could have led to impression that you should expect what you described in your question, I guess.

One last thing
static void MyMethod(string country = "Norway")
    // ^^^^ this is the return type

If a method has a return type of void it doesn't return a value. In your case, you have output (which is different) because that's what Console.WriteLine does.
If it had anything other than void, let's say string, that would mean it returns a value of that type.
It would look like this (example)
static string MyMethod(string country = "Norway")
{
    return $"Country: {country}"; // << Note the "return" statement!
}

Usually, you'd want to use the returned value somehow in the calling code. Example:
// Assume this code is in the Main method
var countryString = MyMethod("Sweden");
Console.WriteLine(countryString);


The Main method is one of the patterns the compiler uses to define an "entry point" for an executable. Your code can have many, many methods. Only the Main method (or rather: the entry point) is started when you launch the application.
In modern C#, you can also have top-level statements, which replace the Main convention. This is equivalent and perhaps clearer:
// important: not inside a type here
MyMethod("Sweden");
MyMethod("India");
MyMethod();
MyMethod("USA");

static void MyMethod(string country = "Norway")
{
  Console.WriteLine(country);
}

